# WCF functionality in Class

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, data-binding, serialization

I've recently converted a WPF application over to use a WCF service (written for an associated website with the aim to convert the app).

Everything has gone fine bar some real time data binding I was doing from the models.

```
public decimal? SalePrice
    {
        get { return _salePrice; }
        set
        {
            _salePrice = value;
            TotalSalesPrice = value + _warranty;
        }
    }
```

In References.cs, this turns into

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Nullable<decimal> SalePrice {
        get {
            return this.SalePriceField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.SalePriceField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.SalePriceField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SalePrice");
            }
        }
    }
```

Forms would then be kept up to date using INotifyPropertyChanged.

What is the best approach for tackling this?

I have written a separate class for this client side functionality for one, but there are multiple classes like this and that seems an extremely non semantic and long way of doing things. I noticed they were partial and tried to make them virtual and then have a ovveride client side, but the virtual property was removed as it was serialised.

Any help greatly appreciated,
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the generated DataContracts for data binding. I think it is a real shame that they implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the generated files because it encourages people to do the wrong thing

The data contract is simply the view of the data according to the service. It is not the view of the data that your forms/windows will necessarily need.

You should treat the service representation of the data as your model and bind your views to a ViewModel that renders the data in the most convenient way for the View. This also means that as the service evolves your data binding will not break and you know that all the changes you will have to do can be done in the viewmodel

Comment: So you would have a version of the object for the service (so Reference.cs). Then have a completely separate folder with local versions of the objects for client side use according to the platform it is being used by?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily have a one to one mapping with the reference.cs objects. I would have a class that presents all of the data the view uses (a viewmodel) and put state on this class that was meaningful to the view. So the UI class decomposition would depend on the needs of the views